# match multi line string with reguar exprssions and sticky flag in JS

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match a multi line string with the following pattern:
$[any characters]$$[any characters]$ 
this can be preceded with any characters and followed by any number of characters.
Also it should match even if there is a new line in the [any characters]

what i have done so far is:

```
/\$.*\$\$.*\$/myg
```

this finds the correct match if it's at the start and add to it the whole line if i added one $ after the first match which is not what i require from the y(sticky flag). 
also, even though i added the right flags, this doesn't match anything in the new lines.

I would also like to find the index of each match and store the whole matches in an array to process it and find the [any characters] and replace the whole match with the first part of it.

I will be happy with any hints or a good guide.
thanks in advance

Comment: `m` modifier does not do anything here since you have no `^` and `$` anchors in the pattern. No idea why you think you need a sticky flag. Try `/\$[\s\S]*?\$\$[^$]*\$/g`

Comment: i thought that i needed m so it can match patterns even if part of it is in a new line.
your regex is almost perfect. I don't know why it match this though:
$dfas$ $another$$test$

Comment: it matches the whole thing while it should have ignored the first part
that is $dfas$

Comment: Ok, so you need [`/\$[^$]*\$\$[^$]*\$/g`](https://regex101.com/r/711Fq8/1)?

Comment: i am using this website to test it and your code is giving me similar result to my latest trial
https://regex101.com/r/ejn834/2/

Comment: You see, with sticky, you can only get 1 match. If you need all, remove `y`.

Comment: awesome , thanks alot

Comment: can you please answer the question instead of a comment so i can tick the right answer?
thanks again.

Comment: @MateusA. It seems that OP needs the shortest window between `$` and `$`, so `[\s\S]*?` does not work, see my top comment.

Comment: @Ali123 I added an answer with explanations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need to match a `$` followed with any chars other than `$` up to `$$` substring, and then again any chars other than `$` up to the first `$`. Use

```
/\$[^$]*\$\$[^$]*\$/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/t3Sgi6/1)

Note that the `m` modifier does not do anything here since you have no `^` and `$` anchors in the pattern. `m` will make `^` match the start of a line rather than the start of a string, and `$` will match the end of the line. The `y` sticky modifier will only make the regex match once at the current `RegExp.lastIndex`, so to get all matches, you need to remove it and use `g`. See [this `RegExp.prototype.sticky` reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/sticky):

> A regular expression defined as both `sticky` and `global` ignores the `global` flag.

**Pattern details**

- `\$` - a single `$` char
- `[^$]*` - 0+ chars other than `$`
- `\$\$` -  two consecutive `$` symbols
- `[^$]*` - 0+ chars other than `$`
- `\$` - a `$`.